# Verifying if TELNET command is completed

Tags: c, sockets, telnet

How do I verify if a TELNET command issued by a client is completed on the server, using raw telnet options in C?

recv(...) waits for buffer input, however does not wait till the command is completed.

Does the wait need to be at a socket level? Or, is there a TELNET option for this? (I haven't found any yet through my searching)

man socket shows that select/poll can be used to verify the socket FD is open to reading/writing; but I don't think this is the right way.

Any help or at least direction would be helpful.

Comment: When you get a prompt string back?

Comment: I am communicating with multiple programs, which individually have prompt strings. It is what I thought of initially. That would be a dirty way of solving, but I'm sure there is something more elegant.

Comment: Are you trying to write your own telnet server? Did you read the Telnet specification yet? Telnet commands have a very specific structure to them.  You are reading raw data from the socket, so you have to parse what you receive, and if a command is incomplete than you have to go back to the socket and read more raw bytes to finish the parsing, reading and parsing in a loop as needed until you have received a full command, then you can process it.  This is basic socket programming 101 kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean commands that you are running on the remote host, rather than telnet commands (`IAC DON'T ECHO` etc.) there is no way to do what you want. The telnet connection is just a terminal, passing characters back and forth. It has no idea whether any of those characters represent commands and responses to the program on the other side.

So really the question is about how to programmatically operate some command-line interface that was designed for interactive use. The answer is going to depend on the the command-line interface itself, not on the method you use to connect to it (telnet, ssh, RS232 serial... you'd have the same problem in any case).

The human operator that the command-line interface was designed for is required to understand the prompts, and also be intelligent enough to respond to the non-appearance of an expected prompt. Writing a program to do that for a specific command-line interface can be difficult, unless you're lucky and it has a command to enter a non-interactive mode with structured responses.

The tool that people usually use to write that kind of program is [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: Thanks. I'll settle on that.